# Select 3 tables in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm a new in Zend.
In my model Default_Model_ApplicationMapper, I wanna use a db-table Application_Model_DbTable_Application to run a query like that

```
"Select * from application as a, category as c, user as u where a.user_id = u.id and a.category_id = c.id";
```

I tried this:

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Application();
$select = $table->select()->from(array('a' => 'application'))
->from(array('c' => 'category'))
->from(array('u' => 'user'))
->where('a.user_id = u.id and a.category_id = c.id');
```

Of course this thing does not work.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: You need table joins http://zendgeek.blogspot.in/2009/07/zend-framework-sql-joins-examples.html

Comment: My teacher doesnt like to join 3 tables :(

Comment: The query that you have written is an example of join itself. It does not use Join keyword though, execution plan remains same (in case of inner joins).

Comment: yes! I know, I wanna use join keyword but my teach said that using this way is faster. I don't think so but he is my teacher, if he's not happy, i will fail my final.

Comment: I don't think your teacher know what the hell he is teaching. This method will likely work when executed against Zend_Db_Adapter or a naked Zend_Db_Table. Against a DbTable Model this method is at best semantically uncomfortable.

Comment: Yup I just tried to get this kind of thing to work and Zend_Db_Select throws a fit.

Comment: `$select = $table->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('a' => 'application'))
->join(array('c' => 'category'), 'c.id = u.cat_id');`
i tried this and echo $select i got: `SELECT a.*, c.* FROM application AS a INNER JOIN category AS c ON c.id = u.cat_id`
then i call
`$rowset = $table->fetchAll($select);`
i got a fatal error!

Comment: You can't do any sort of joins with a class, that is extending Zend_Db_Table. What you need to to, is `$table->getAdapter()`, and create `select()` and `fetchAll()` from the adapter!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `from(array('a' => 'table'))` three times, try using `from(array('a' => 'table1', 'b' => 'table2', 'c' => 'table3'))`.

Comment: Also, instead of using `AND` in your `where()` function, use the `where()` function once for each condition you want to add. The `AND` operator is implied when you add more than one. If you want to use and `OR` operator, use the `orWhere()` function instead.

Comment: I tried this one, more simple
$select = $table->select()->from(array('user' => 'u'))->where('id=',0);
$rowset = $table->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
but it still does not work.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)'

Comment: Well that only means that you have not created an ErrorController, which could show you the real errors.  Maybe take a look at some logs, to see what is the actual problem with the query?

Comment: I created an ErrorController but not in my module. Do i need it?

Comment: @HungNV you'll need to use `->where('id = ?', 0)`. The `?` indicates where the value (the second argument) should be inserted in the condition string.